# Getting electricity to the woodshed

Tags: installation

Have 200ft from panel  box to wood she'd  what kind of wire am breaker for air compressor refrigerator two hanging light 4 Outlets table saw

Comment: If you're in the US, hire an electrician. I don't think it's legal anywhere in the US to run service on your own. That said, if you are not an electrician yourself, ***wiring into you breaker panel can be extremely dangerous. So I do not, at all, recommend doing it yourself***.

Comment: Welcome to DIY.SE! Your question is lacking a lot of information, which makes it impossible to answer properly. For instance, are you wanting to put a subpanel in the shed? What voltage do you need? How much current or power does each device draw? Direct bury or conduit? Please edit this information into your question

Comment: How many square feet is the shed?  What are the wattage ratings on the air compressor, table saw, and fridge?

Comment: Be as specific as you can about the compressor... startup loads are way higher than running loads on many models.

Comment: In Some states it is legal to run your own services with permits but much more information is needed. This question is being closed due to lack of information please post a new question with voltages required, the size of the shed and size of compressor.

Comment: it's YOUR property. You get to use it reasonably (eg a house in R1 zoning).   If excessive regulations block reasonable use, that is a regulatory "taking" under the 5th amendment, and they must pay for the property or loss-of-use.  They cannot arbitrarily require "hire a professional" when a more efficient method (permits, inspections) can accomplish the same goal.  If a city blocks you, sue them.  Suing isn't free, but freedom isn't free.  Many have been called to serve, and some have paid more dearly.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming 110/120V power, your big loads will be the

- compressor (10-16 amps)
- table saw (6-13 amps for a common one, more for a big one)
- 6-10 amps for the dust collector everyone forgets to mention
- Refrigerator is pretty minimal, probably 5 amps at 120V peak.
- Lights are nothin unless you're setting up sodium lights to grow herb.
- those outlets are a mystery, let's assume one heater at 15A and that if you're running anything else, the table saw is turned off.

Sounds like about 60 amps at 120V.  Any one circuit can't be more than 20A, and four big loads are too large to share a 20A circuit with each other... so you need 4 circuits.  You can only bring 2 from the house without a sub-panel (via MWBC). So you need a 120/240V sub-panel.

A 30A (per side, two sides) sub-panel would just squeak by, but you might as well go 40A because it'll be the same size of wire.  Best practices (3% voltage drop worst case) call for 6 AWG wire (4 AWG if aluminum).  But if you can live with 5% voltage drop worst-case, you can use 8 AWG wire (6 aluminum).  Aluminum is half the cost when the wires get this big.

If you are very careful with power use, you might get away with a single 20A 120/240V MWBC, perhaps with 10 AWG cable (12 AWG if you can live with 6% voltage drop at max load)... but the limitations will be annoying.

You can either bury UF cable, or lay rigid metal conduit and run individual THWN wires.

There are tricks you can do with transformers to carry a lot more power on thinner wire, but given the short distance, I think "throwing aluminum at the problem" is going to end up being the cheapest way to go.